# Check if path is directory or file C#

Tags: c#

I tried to check if path to deleted directory or file is path to directory or file. I found this code:

```
FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(@"C:\Example");
if (attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory))
    MessageBox.Show("It's a directory");
else
    MessageBox.Show("It's a file");
```

However this code is not working with deleted directory or file.

I have two folders

```
C:\Dir1
C:\Dir2
```

In Dir1 there are normal files like "test.txt", in Dir2 there are compressed files like "test.rar" or "test.zip" and I need to delete file in Dir2 when file in Dir1 is deleted.

Something I tried, but nothing works.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: If it has been deleted, it no longer exists, does it matter what it was when it existed?

Comment: However I need to delete this from another folder, so I need to know if its file or directory (because of extension)

Comment: Do you need to delete it (which will happen in the future) or do you want to check what a deleted file or directory was when it existed (which happened in the past)?

Comment: Well, a Directory doesn't have an extension.  So if you add the extension, it will always be a file?

Comment: A directory can end with `.jpg` just fine. Whether that technically is *counted* as an extension is one thing, whether all/most path parsing implementations will count it as an extension is another.

Comment: From your edited question it sounds like you need to check whether the file or directory you want to delete is a file or directory. Since this still exists it should work. Can you clarify what you're having problems with because the question is quite unclear right now.

Answer (score 1):

If the object represented by a path does not exist or has been deleted from the file system, all you've got is a string representing a file system path: it's not anything.

The normal convention for indicating that a path is intended to be a directory (rather than a file) is to terminate it with a directory separator, so

```
c:\foo\bar\baz\bat
```

is taken to indicate a file, while

```
c:\foo\bar\baz\bat\
```

is taken to indicate a directory.

If what you want is to delete a file system entry (either a file, or a directory, recursively deleting its contents and subdirectories), something like should suffice:

```
public void DeleteFileOrDirectory( string path )
{

  try
  {
    File.Delete( path ) ;
  }
  catch ( UnauthorizedAccessException )
  {
    // If we get here,
    // - the caller lacks the required permissions, or
    // - the file has its read-only attribute set, or
    // - the file is a directory.
    //
    // Either way: intentionally swallow the exception and continue.
  }

  try
  {
    Directory.Delete( path , true ) ;
  }
  catch ( DirectoryNotFoundException )
  {
    // If we get here,
    // - path does not exist or could not be found
    // - path refers to a file instead of a directory
    // - the path is invalid (e.g., on an unmapped drive or the like)
    //
    // Either way: intentationally swallow the exception and continue
  }

  return ;
}
```

One should note that there are any number of exceptions that can be thrown during this process.